# Is it possible to create an array from the frequency of chars within a string?

Tags: c#, string, linq, frequency-analysis

Essentially, I found an old piece of LINQ C# code that counted the most frequent letter in a certain string. However, I'm using frequency analysis to solve a decoded text that has been shift-ciphered so I'm wanting it to return not just the most popular char, but a char array ordered by frequency of appearance.

Here is the LINQ code I found on here:

```
input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key
```

Comment: Oh come on, is this a "do my work for me" question? I suggest you go learn LINQ, and understand what that piece of code does. **Who the heck upvotes this?**

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to know whether this code is good? Or do you want an optimized version?

Comment: Believe me R. Martinho Fernandes, I have been out of the loop for some time, never used LINQ before and I've exhausted myself trying to research how I can do this. Thought I might be able to get help on here

Comment: Since you never used LINQ before, I stand by my suggestion of learning LINQ.

Comment: I'll only be using it for this one piece of string-searching. I don't think learning LINQ will be appropriate given my time constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you pretty much have it already.

```
input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `.First().Key` with `.Select(group => group.Key)` should return to you the characters sorted by frequency in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use LINQ, which might be understandable without learning LINQ:

```
// count all the frequencies
var frequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>;
foreach(char c in input)
{
    if(frequencies.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        frequencies[c]++;
    }
    else
    {
        frequencies.Add(c, 1);
    }
}
// Get the characters
var characters = new List<char>(frequencies.Keys);
// Sort them
characters.Sort((x, y) => frequencies[x].CompareTo(frequencies[y]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(group => group.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The information is all there, just don't throw it away:

```
Dictionary<char, int> count =
  input.GroupBy(g => g).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Oh, right, you just want the characters, not their frequency. Then you have to throw away some of the information:

```
char[] chars =
  input.GroupBy(g => g).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Will also be using this too, much appreciated!